# Select an Entity using QueryExpression? C# Dynamics CRM Online 2015

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-online

In dynamics CRM online 2015 we have installed custom extensions for our company however we can't pull data for it, our code:

```
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression();
qe.EntityName = "tsg_project";
qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
qe.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("name");
EntityCollection retrieved = serviceA.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

This returns null, when in dynamics it's:
[image: dynamics crm]

However for 'account' this works fine.

How could I get this to work?

Comment: What exactly is your Image from?

Answer (score 2):

your query will throw an error because a custom entity can't contain an attribute called `name` but probably is `tsg_name`.

so your code needs to be:

```
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression("tsg_project");
qe.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("tsg_name");
EntityCollection retrieved = serviceA.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```